# Created a nested Named List in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have a list like so:

```
df = list(
Happy = c('Yes','No','Maybe'),
Satisfaction = c('Strongly Agree','Agree','Disagree','Strongly Disagree')
)
```

but what I need

```
df = list(
    Happy = c('Yes'='Happy-yes','No'='Happy-yes','Maybe'='Happy-maybe'),
    Satisfaction = c('Strongly Agree'='Satisfaction-Strongly Agree",'Agree'="Satisfaction-Agree",'Disagree'='Satisfaction-Disagree','Strongly Disagree'='Satisfaction-Strongly Disagree'))
```

I will then pass this list into choices() input in Shiny but this way I have a way to map back the response to a grouping of the named list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map` to `paste` together, and `setNames` to label the new value with the old value:

```
Map(function(nm,x) setNames(paste(nm,x,sep="-"),x), names(df), df)
#$Happy
#          Yes            No         Maybe 
#  "Happy-Yes"    "Happy-No" "Happy-Maybe" 
# 
#$Satisfaction
#                  Strongly Agree                            Agree 
#   "Satisfaction-Strongly Agree"             "Satisfaction-Agree" 
#                        Disagree                Strongly Disagree 
#         "Satisfaction-Disagree" "Satisfaction-Strongly Disagree"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can choose `lapply` to do it:

```
dfx <- lapply(1:length(df), function(i)paste0(names(df)[i],"-",df[[i]]))
dfxf <- lapply(1:length(dfx), function(i) `names<-`((dfx[[i]]), df[[i]]))
names(dfxf) <- names(df)
```

**Output**:

```
 > dfxf
$Happy
          Yes            No         Maybe 
  "Happy-Yes"    "Happy-No" "Happy-Maybe" 

$Satisfaction
                  Strongly Agree 
   "Satisfaction-Strongly Agree" 
                           Agree 
            "Satisfaction-Agree" 
                        Disagree 
         "Satisfaction-Disagree" 
               Strongly Disagree 
"Satisfaction-Strongly Disagree"
```

**Please Note here**, OP desired output is having little typo it seems , as you can see that Instead of "Happy-No" it says "Happy-Yes" in the second element of first list also the casing is off (Assuming this is the case).